# Mono: socket select timed out

Tags: asp.net, mono

I'm testing asp.net on fastcgi-mono-server4 (ubuntu server 11.04) and native .net framework (windows server 2008) by Siege.

My .aspx page makes request like this (I get JSON):

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    var url = "http://some_host/location";

    var request = WebRequest.Create( url ) as HttpWebRequest;

    using ( var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse )
        using ( var reader = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream() ))
            Content.InnerText = reader.ReadToEnd();
   Console.WriteLine ("Mono");
}
```

When I make request to .aspx page which is on Windows Server everything is Ok:

```
siege -d0.1 -c200 -r10 windowsserver/TestPage.aspx
Transactions:                    2000 hits
Availability:                 100.00 %
Elapsed time:                   1.10 secs
Response time:                  0.07 secs
Transaction rate:            1815.60 trans/sec
```

When I make request to .aspx page which is on Ubuntu Server there is something strange:

```
siege -d0.1 -c200 -r10 ubuntuserver/TestPage.aspx
Transactions:                    1472 hits
Availability:                  73.60 %
Elapsed time:                  91.22 secs
Response time:                  1.10 secs
Transaction rate:              16.14 trans/sec
```

And I have a lot of messages like this:

```
[alert] socket: 675498112 select timed out: Operation timed out
```

The hardware on Ubuntu is more powerful than on Windows (and Windows is on virtual machine).

If I make request to .aspx page without requests to another host (page is on Ubuntu)   - everything is Ok. Mono is fast at this situation.

So what could be the problem? Ubuntu or fastcgi-mono-server4

Answer (score 0):

On Windows/IIS/ASP.NET, the thread pool dedicated to ASP.NET has limited threads, and your page design can easily exhaust it (and possibly socket user ports further) if the request to other host is slow. Luckily your test does not show that contention, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268

But if Mono/ASP.NET uses the same thread pool way, then you should check if the error message was caused by exhausted thread pool or user port. I am not familiar with Linux/Mono, but it should have similar settings which you can explore.